# Responsive Absolute positiing side advert

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm having trouble getting `.ad` to position correctly by using position:absolute on my responsive design.

The problem I have is that if I nest the  inside the `.container` it works fine but as in my actual site it will be lopping through this will also loop the `.ad` box multiple times, so I need to position the div outside of my looped code which is where I have trouble making it resize with the design.

In the fiddle it sits in the top right hand side but I want this to stick next to the pink column and overlap the black column.

http://jsfiddle.net/zbe5vf0n/5/

```
body{color:#fff; display:flex; flex-direction:column;}
.fullcontainer{width:100%; background:#ff00ff; height:400px;height:auto;}
.container{  width:300px; height:auto; margin: 0 auto;background:#000; position:relative;}
.col1{display:flex; flex:1; margin-right:100px; background:#ff0000;}
.ad{position:absolute; z-index:1;top:0px; right:0px;height:300px; width:90px; background:#ccc;}

<div class="fullcontainer">aa
<div class="container">
<div class="col1">col1</div>
</div>
<div class="fullcontainer">aa
<div class="container">
<div class="col1">adad</br>
dfdfs</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ad"></div>
```

Comment: Advice - don't use .ad class, because users with ad blocker won't be able to see it.

Comment: Thanks I'll rename this

Answer (score 1):

Absolute position works only when they are nested inside a relative positioned element.
So the solution for you would be to add:

```
.fullcontainer {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zbe5vf0n/11/ I'd like it to be relative to .container so it stays in the black column however the .ad div needs to be outside the .container div

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `.ad` div in `.container` div. So `.ad` div can be positioned relative to `.container` div. But add the `.ad` div only to the first `.container` div.

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/oe51297k/